# Detecting the fault in my sed command

Tags: sed

I am creating a command to replace all instances of `; f.` to `, (frequent).` . So i wrote `sed -i 's:;[:space:]f.:,[:space:](frequent).:g'` with out any change then i wrote `sed -i 's:; f.:, (frequent).:g'` to only find that it replaces all  instances of `f` that has been written after a `;` so its turning `; find` to `, (frequent).ind`

Will any one please let me know about my fault and how to rectify it ?

Comment: Did you try `sed -i 's/; f./, (frequent)./g'`? I just tried it on a file and it worked.

Comment: Its actually same as the second command. As `sed` supports various delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the first case is quoting: If you want to use `:` as the separator, you cannot use it unquoted in character spaces. Also, `.` has a special meaning in a regular expression - it matches any character. To match the literal dot, use `\.`. Moreover, `[:space:]` must be used inside a character class, so you should use `[[:space:]]`. Finally, character classes have no meaning in the replacement part of the expression.

This should work:

```
sed 's/;[[:space:]]f\./, (frequent)./g'
```